# Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY is not called in Application

Tags: android, application-lifecycle

I want to call some method when a user exits an application (see [1](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle), [2](https://dev.to/nisrulz/is-your-android-library-lifecycle-aware-2di) for help).

```
class BaseApplication : Application(), LifecycleObserver {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        // Register observer.
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE) 
    fun init() {
        println("*** called onCreate()")
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START) 
    fun LibOnStart() {
        println("*** called onStart()")
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP) 
    fun LibOnStop() {
        println("*** called onStop()")
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME) 
    fun LibOnResume() {
        println("*** called onResume()")
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE) 
    fun LibOnPause() {
        println("*** called onPause()")
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY) 
    fun cleanup() {
        println("*** called onDestroy()")
    }
}
```

These events are fired except `ON_DESTROY`.

```
I/System.out: *** called onPause() of Activity
I/System.out: *** called onStop() of Activity
```

Probably `Application` doesn't clean up from memory. If I swipe the application from recent list or force stop, it won't fire `destroy` event. Maybe these events work right in an `Activity`. How to catch `destroy` event in the `Application`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner) claims that

> You can consider this LifecycleOwner as the composite of all of your
> Activities, except that Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE will be dispatched
> once and Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY will never be dispatched.

So there is no way to process `onDestroy` in application.

Alternatively, you can try to use [`onTaskRemoved`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent)) callback of `Service` class to catch the moment when the app is removed from recents.

Comment: Could you show me any example?>